# Music players isn't finding tracks on Samsung Galaxy S3!

Tags: music-player, google-play-music, media-files

The music player in Samsung galaxy s3 isn't finding my tracks. I tried different application like google play music but nothing seems to read my tracks at all. 
This problems happened suddenly I don't know why. 
I tried rebooting the phone but with no hope.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by going to **Settings->More->Application manager->All->media storage**.

I tapped **Media Storage** then **Clear Data**.

Then, at **Settings->More->Application manager->All->My Files**, I tapped **Clear Data** too.

Finally, I restarted the phone. And it worked.